# Rotating a plate ( triangular mesh) to form a cylinder

Tags: opengl, math, animation, graphics, mesh

I have a triangular mesh, which is a square in shape and I want to transform it to a cylinder i.e. A cylinder of triangular mesh. In other words, I have a mesh of cloth and I want to wrap it around a cylinder so that it takes the shape of cylinder. Please tell me any method to do above transformation or any other suggestion to wrap a cloth ( which is in the form of triangular mesh) around a cylinder

Comment: For a naïve approach, use the mapping (x, y) ↦ (r cos(x), r sin(x), y) where (x, y) are taken as coordinates in your plane (the one containing the square), to form a homotopy.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you looking for information on how to "texture" the cloth, over a cylindrical object that is drawn using OpenGL ?

Comment: I am equally confused by this. To what extent is OpenGL involved in this question? These days you can handle cloth surfaces using tessellation shaders and/or geometry shaders and deform your control points by this cylinder you are discussing. This [NV article](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/direct3d/Source/Cloth/doc/Cloth.pdf) illustrates how to do it in GL3/DX10 class hardware using transform feedback (called stream output in the D3D world).